# How to send keystroke to tray application with AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey, window

I have a tray application, which is listening for keystroke. Unfortunately, this keystroke is intercepted by very progressive Windows 8 interface. I don't need this progress, I need my old application receive this keystroke.

How to pass it to it with AutoHotKey?

Note: I don't want to change active window or something.

Comment: Please provide more information such as what keystroke you are trying to send.